# Write a program that can be used by a small theater to sell tickets for performances. Read data from inputfile

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, multidimensional-array, ifstream

Need help writing a program for class.  Here were the posted instructions:

> Step 1:  The program should have a FUNCTION that displays a screen that shows which seats are available and which are taken.  Seats that are taken should be represented by a # symbol and seats that are available should be represented by a * symbol.    The first thing your program should do is initialize all of the seats to available (*) and display the seating chart.  (HINT: The seating chart should be a two dimensional array.)
>
> Step 2:  Each row in the auditorium has a different ticket price.  So tickets in row 0 may be 5.00 each and tickets in row 1 may be 10.00 each.  Your program should have a FUNCTION that reads the ticket price of each row from an input file called prices.dat.  The ticket price for each row should be stored in a one dimensional array.
>
> Step 3:  Your program should have variables tracking the total number of tickets sold and the total revenue for all tickets sold.
>
> Step 4: 
>   Your program should allow the user to sell tickets one at a time.  The user should be able to sell as many tickets as they would like (you need a loop for this). Do this with some sort of prompt or menu asking the user if they would like to sell another ticket.  Don’t forget to validate input data if you need to.
>
> To allow the user to sell a ticket your program should have the user enter a row number and a seat number for the ticket they would like to sell.  The program should do four things with this information:
>
> 1. It should check to see if the seat is available.  If the seat is taken the program should not allow the user to sell the ticket.  If this happens, print a message to the user saying the ticket is not available and prompt the user to see if they would like to sell another ticket.
> 2. If the seat is available the program should update the seating chart by putting a taken symbol (#) in that seat’s position in the chart.
> 3. The program should then look up the row price for the seat sold.  Your program should have a variable tracking the total revenue, the price of the seat sold should be added to this total after each sale.
> 4. Your program should have a variable tracking the total tickets sold.  The next thing your program should do when selling a ticket is update the total tickets sold.
>
> Step 5: Once the user is finished selling tickets print out an updated seating chart followed by the total tickets sold and the total revenue generate from those tickets.
>
> NOTE:  You are required to use two arrays in this program, one for the seating chart and one to store the prices for each row.  You are also required to use two functions:  one to display the seating chart and one to read in the price per row data and store it in the array with the prices for each row in it.  You may use other functions if you want to but they are not required.
>
> Note: The test data file for this run: prices.txt
>
> ```
> 10
> 10
> 10
> 9
> 9
> 9
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 7
> 7
> 7
> 6
> 6
> 6
> ```

---

I am stuck on step two where it says:

> "Your program should have a FUNCTION that reads the ticket price of each row from an input file called prices.dat.  The ticket price for each row should be stored in a one dimensional array."

I have no idea on how to create input files or check them for that matter.
Here is my code so far.  I stopped in my case '1' after checking for duplicate seats.  How would I then match the row with the price I want to charge from a data file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const int numberOfRow = 15;
const int numberOfCol = 20;

void print(char matrix[][20], int numberOfRow, int numberOfCol);

int main()
{
char matrix[numberOfRow][numberOfCol], seat[numberOfRow][numberOfCol];
char option;
int i, j;
int row,col;
int ticketsold = 0;
bool another =true;

for(i = 0; i < numberOfRow; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < numberOfCol; j++)
        matrix[i][j] = '*';

while(another)
{
    print( matrix, numberOfRow, numberOfCol );

    cout << "\nMenu:\n";
    cout << "1)  Buy ticket\n";
    cout << "2)  Total sell and exit\n\n";
    cout << "Enter your choice  : ";
    cin >> option;
    cout << endl << endl;

    switch (option)
    {
    case '1' :
        {
            cout << "Enter row: ";
            cin >> row;
            cout << "\nEnter seat: ";
            cin >> col;

            if( matrix[row][col] == '*')
                {
                    matrix[row][col] = '#';
                    ticketsold++;
                }
              else
                { 
                  cout << "Invalid seat choice";
                }


            //total revenue
        }

    /*case '2' :
        {
            another=false;
        }

    default :
        cout << "Invalid choice";*/

    }
}





system("pause");
}


void print(char matrix[][20], int numberOfRow, int numberOfCol)
{
int row, col, i, j;

cout << "* Seats available\n";
cout << "# Reserved Seats\n";
cout << "Seats:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19" <<  endl;

for(i = 0; i < numberOfRow; i++)
{
    cout << "Row" << setw(3) << i;
    for(j=0; numberOfCol > j; j++)
        cout << setw(3) << matrix[i][j];

    cout << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: If your question is just "how do you read a file with numbers, one per line, and store it in a one-dimensional array", why include so much extraneous code and text?

Answer (score 0):

The below program is almost similar to your requirement, except reading input from file. 
This program will read input from console (user has to key-in price for each row.)
Again, this is not exactly how you want, but I hope it will help you. If possible, soon I'll post another program which can read input from file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int Show_Menu ();       
void Show_Chart ();     
const char FULL = '*';  
const char EMPTY = '#'; 
const int rows = 15;    
const int columns = 30; 
char map [rows][columns];
double price;
int total = 0;
int seat = 450;
int seat2 = 0;
int Quit = 1;
int main ()
{
const int Num_Rows = 15;
int price [Num_Rows];
int row2, column2, cost;
int answer;

    cout << "\t*********************************************************" << endl;
    cout << "\t*                                                       *" << endl;
    cout << "\t*    Welcome to our small town Theater                  *" << endl;
    cout << "\t*                                                       *" << endl;
    cout << "\t*********************************************************" << endl;
    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int count = 0; count < rows; count++)
        {
            cout << "Please enter the price for row " << (count + 1) << ": ";
                cin >> price [count];

        }
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                map [i][j] = EMPTY;
        }
int choice;
    do
    {
        choice = Show_Menu();
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                cout << "View Seat Prices\n\n";

                for (int count = 0; count < rows; count++)
                {
                    cout << "The price for row " << (count + 1) << ": ";
                    cout << price [count] << endl;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Purchase a Ticket\n\n";
                do 
                {
                    cout << "Please select the row you would like to sit in: ";
                    cin >> row2;
                    cout << "Please select the seat you would like to sit in: ";
                    cin >> column2;
                    if (map [row2] [column2] == '*')
                        {
                            cout << "Sorry that seat is sold-out, Please select a new seat.";
                            cout << endl;
                        }
                    else 
                    {
                        cost = price [row2] + 0;
                        total = total + cost;
                        cout << "That ticket costs: " << cost << endl;
                        cout << "Confirm Purchase? Enter (1 = YES / 2 = NO)";
                        cin >> answer;
                        seat = seat - answer;
                        seat2 += answer;

                        if (answer == 1)
                        { 
                            cout << "Your ticket purchase has been confirmed." << endl;
                            map [row2][column2] = FULL;
                        }
                        else if (answer == 2)
                        {
                            cout << "Would you like to look at another seat? (1 = YES / 2 = NO)";
                            cout << endl;
                            cin >> Quit;
                        }

                        cout << "Would you like to look at another seat?(1 = YES / 2 = NO)";
                        cin >> Quit;
                    }
                }
                while (Quit == 1);

                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "View Available Seats\n\n";
                Show_Chart ();
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "Total ticket sales: "<<total<<".\n\n";
                break;
            case 5:
                cout << "quit\n";
                break;
            default : cout << "Error input\n";
        }
    } while (choice != 5);
return 0;
}
//********************************************************************************
//********************************************************************************
//**                                                                            **
//**                              Define Functions.                          **
//**                                                                            **
//********************************************************************************
//********************************************************************************

int Show_Menu()
{
    int MenuChoice;
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << " \tMAIN MENU\n";
        cout << " 1. View Seat Prices.\n";
        cout << " 2. Purchase a Ticket.\n";
        cout << " 3. View Available Seats.\n";
        cout << " 4. View Ticket Sales.\n";
        cout << " 5. Quit the program.\n";
        cout << "_____________________\n\n";
        cout << "Please enter your choice: ";
        cin >> MenuChoice;
        cout << endl << endl;
    return MenuChoice;
}

void Show_Chart ()
{
    cout << "\tSeats" << endl;
    cout << "   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30\n";
        for (int count = 0; count < 15; count++)
        {
            cout << endl << "Row " << (count + 1);
            for (int count2 = 0; count2 < 30; count2++)
            {
                cout << " " <<  map [count] [count2];
            }
        }
            cout << endl;
}
```